# Parsing recursive JSON strings with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

How to parse the **recursive** JSON strings like below with Gson? Any advices will be appreciated, thx.

[image]

Comment: Gson API list https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Comment: The JSON string is a little special, the key of child "listCity" array is the same with the parent's, a little like recursive structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class inside it

```
public class City {
    String areaId;
    String areaName;
    // other fields here
    List<City> listCity;
}
...
List<City> data;
```